Recrystallisation of optical calcite
I have a sample of optical calcite but it has quite a few internal cracks and I was wondering if I broke off a small clean piece to use as seed crystal and dissolved a large amount of calcium carbonate in a solution would it be possible to grow a new clean crystal in solution or just get a new one?

That's not something that can easily be done at home.

No, it's completely impractical outside very special circumstances.
Calcite can be grown in hydrotermal conditions, meaning aqueous solutions of $\ce{NH4Br}$ at temperature 300 °C and pressure 60–80 MPa [1], with growth speed of about 0.05 - 0.20 mm/day. These conditions require a special reactor and a thermostat. It's doable in specialized lab, but not at home.
Your best bet is searching and purchasing a suitable sample online.
[1] https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcrysgro.2004.11.041
